# union find set algorithm return parent[v] = find_set(parent[v]); means

Tags: disjoint-sets, disjoint-union

> ```
> int find_set(int v) {
> if (v == parent[v])
>     return v;
> return parent[v] = find_set(parent[v]); }
> ```

This is a slice of code of disjoin set algorithm
can i ask what is the meaning and purpose of return parent[v] = find_set(parent[v]);?
usually the return are integers,boolean,or other data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of code (`parent[v] = find_set(parent[v]);`) is an heuristic optimization called **path compression**, a simple and highly effective heuristic. Path compression makes that each node on the `find_set` path points directly to the root. Further calls to find_set on any node in the path before will be very fast. The time complexity of this heuristic is shown below.

As stated in the book Introduction to Algorithms (Cormen, page 571-572), 3rd Edition:

> Alone, union by rank yields a running time
> of *O(m log n)*, and this bound is tight.
> Although we shall not prove it here, for a sequence of n MAKE-SET operations
> (and hence at most *n - 1* UNION operations) and f FIND-SET operations,
> the path-compression heuristic alone gives a worst-case running time of *O(n + f * (1 + log<sub>2 + f/n</sub>n))*.

> When we use both union by rank and path compression, the worst-case running
> time is *O(m α(n))*, where *α(n)* is a very slowly growing function, which we define
> in Section 21.4. In any conceivable application of a disjoint-set data structure,
> *α(n) ≤ 4*; thus, we can view the running time as linear in *m* in all practical situations. Strictly speaking, however, it is superlinear.

You can learn more about it by reading that book.

Comment: actually that line are two lines compressed in one (set the root as parent of current node and returning the root) only available in a few languages like C family. If you don't include the return then your function would be void. You want to return the root always, path compression is the first (parent[v] = find_set(parent[v])) and find_set code is the second (return root -> which is parent[v] because of path compression)